# How to search from array of SwiftyJSON objects?

Tags: ios, swift, swifty-json

I have an SwiftyJSON object.

How to search by key(name) from the array of [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) object.

For Example :

```
let arrCountry = [JSON]()
```

Now one country array contains

```
{
    countryid : "1"
    name : "New York"
},
{
    countryid : "2"
    name : "Sydeny"
}
```

How to search by predicate or something?

If I search "y" from the array then it should return both object (Because both contains "y") in another JSON array. And If I type "Syd" then it should return only one object in JSON array. As LIKE query in SQL. And as we are doing with predicates...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Get the array from the `JSON` object with `arrayObject`, cast it to the proper type and apply the `filter` function, in this example to find the item whose `name` is `def`

```
if let array = arrCountry.arrayObject as? [[String:String]],
   foundItem = array.first(where: { $0["name"] == "def"}) {
   print(foundItem)
}
```

Edit: For a refined search with `NSPredicate` and a `JSON` result use this

```
let searchText = "y"
let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[cd] %@", searchText)
if let array = arrCountry.arrayObject as? [[String:String]] {
    let foundItems = JSON(array.filter{ searchPredicate.evaluateWithObject($0) })
    print(foundItems)
}
```

Comment: I want searched JSON objects back. And I want to found any character available in name then it should return that object.

Comment: Then please ask a more specific question.

Comment: it gives error : **Value of type '[JSON]' has no member 'arrayObject'**

Comment: @HardikShekhat If the object is of type `[JSON]` it must have a member `arrayObject`. Do you use the `SwiftyJSON` library matching your Swift version?

Comment: @vadian what should i have to do if my swiftyjson array contain [[String:Any]].

Comment: Then you have to cast `as? [[String:Any]],` and `array.first(where: { $0["name"] as! String == "def" })`

Comment: i have this json https://codebeautify.org/online-json-editor/cbaf265b 
and i want to find that object that srs_category contain 3.

Comment: Please ask a new question. By the way this object is `[String:[Int]]`

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract the dictionary Array from the JSON Object and the you can apply the Predicate to that array.