# Filter Data in SwiftyJson

Tags: ios, json, swift, nspredicate, swifty-json

I have one SwiftyJson object.

I can not filter that array. I have tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/37497170/4831567. But my json format is different that's why not working.

```
[
    {
        "name": "19860",
        "header": {
            "start_time": "1519270200",
            "end_time": "1519299000",
            "state": "lunch"
        },
        "alerts": "1",
        "venue": {
            "location": "Delhi, India",
            "timezone": "+05:30"
        },
        "srs_category": [
            0,
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "19861",
        "header": {
            "start_time": "1519270200",
            "end_time": "1519299000",
            "state": "Dinner"
        },
        "alerts": "1",
        "venue": {
            "location": "Mumbai, India",
            "timezone": "+05:30"
        },
        "srs_category": [
            1,
            3
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "19862",
        "header": {
            "start_time": "1519270200",
            "end_time": "1519299000",
            "state": "lunch"
        },
        "alerts": "1",
        "venue": {
            "location": "Surat, India",
            "timezone": "+05:30"
        },
        "srs_category": [
            0,
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

i want to find that object that srs_category contain 1. I know it is possible by looping and condition. But i want via NSPredicate. If it is possible then please help me.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a Swift native function rather than `NSPredicate`

`data` represents the `Data` object received from somewhere

```
do {
    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:data) as? [[String:Any]] {
        let srsCategory1 = json.first(where: { dict -> Bool in
            guard let array = dict["srs_category"] as? [Int] else { return false }
            return array.contains(1)
        })
        print(srsCategory1 ?? "not found")
    }
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

If there are multiple items which can match the condition replace `first` with `filter`. Then the result is a non-optional array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is easy way to use SwiftyJSON:

```
    let filtered = JSON(yourArray).arrayValue.filter({
        $0["srs_category"].arrayValue.map({ $0.intValue }).contains(1)
    })
```